# Blenders Directories Are Broken?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, scripting

Trying to open pref scripts directly into Blender and replicates a message of "Directory not supported in this version". I don't understand the problem entirely and theres nothing on Blenders website, this the first I have seen and heard on this topic. Any opinions would be appreciated! Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly... Blenders a bit broken with directories, there's honestly nothing i can say until they update there #NAME system of pref Codec. Sorry but its just a waiting game.

Comment: Glad to help, happy directoring

Comment: @YogurtM8, what worked? I don't see anything instructions in Adam's answer to follow. Would you be able to post what you did to get your problem resolved?

Comment: Sorry, theres nothing that I can do with my problem at the moment, but he explained the problem well. But thanks.